# Get nodes of specified content type with REST

Tags: 8

I want to retrieve all nodes of specified content type (as example'news') with `GET` method with REST,
How can I achieve it?
(first I want try it with [firefox RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) and if it work implement it in my application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that core offers is building a view with a REST display. That is, in fact, the only way in core to have collections (a list of resources) for rest.

See https://www.drupal.org/project/graphql for another approach, that allows to execute a sort of query through services.

Comment: and if I want fetch contents from another source (another website or mobile app), how can I achieve it? create a views with REST display?